# Is this sentence grammatically correct in terms of the agreement of the subjects of the two parts of the sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

I found this sentence in a publication of a world-renowned institution. Is it grammatically correct in terms of the agreement of the subjects of the two parts of the sentence?

> **A reserved boy** in his twenties, **the reserve** could never have been attributed to lack of confidence.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. Please provide the link where you found the sentence, and provide more context. I suspect you misquoted it.

Comment: The two parts don't agree. They're not referring to the same thing. You'll have to explain what your problem is in more detail. Look at this sentence: "A cat lover all his life, his cat Mabel was a companion to the end." It's doing a similar thing, referencing a general topic, and then discussing specifics.

Comment: @StuartF thanks for the answer! Could you tell me how the grammatical structure in your example is called? Does it have a specific name?

Answer (score 1):

It is a strange sentence, but it could use repetition intentionally. Without more context, we will never know. However, this is what it means:

> [***He was***] a reserved boy in his twenties, [***but his***] reserve could never have been attributed to lack of confidence.

So although he was reserved, it was never because he had no confidence in himself.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I aware of what the sentence means. What does not make sense to me is how "the reserved boy" can agree with "the reserve".

Comment: I have indicated that it might be an intentional repetition. It is grammatically correct and it makes sense. Pity you refuse to give more context...

Comment: I am unable to provide any link or context as that sentence was written down in my notes weeks ago to be clarified later. I believe the sentence would be grammatically right if constructed this way: "A reserved boy in his twenties, he has never been prone  to lack of confidence" Here "the reserved boy" and "he" agree with each other.